# Алгоритм перебора

Tags: c++, алгоритм, перебор

*Вчера я написал вопрос об этой же [задаче](https://www.e-olymp.com/uk/problems/3603), слегка улучшил свой алгоритм,* но всё таки хотел бы узнать **как можно решить её алгоритмом перебора.**

> *Юного программиста Васю заинтересовал следующий вопрос: предположим,
>   что мы взвешиваем боксёров на чашечных весах и пользуемся двумя
>   двоичными наборами гирь: граммовым и килограммовым. Понятно, что
>   граммовый набор является стандартным и состоит из гирек весом в 1, 2,
>   4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512 и 1024 грамм. Аналогично обстоит дело
>   и с килограммовым набором – просто гири потяжелее, но при этом их
>   немного меньше… Для простоты далее в этой задаче будем считать, что
>   волшебным образом на прошедшей олимпиаде оказалось, что вес каждого
>   спортсмена в точности мог быть измерен только килограммовым набором.*
>   **Найти количество гирь.**
>   **40 <= вес спортсмена <= 130**.

Суть в том, что я даже не понимаю что да как с этим алгоритмом. Что он должен перебирать? Рассмотрим пример моего решения.

У меня есть число `n = 97` *(для примера)*.
Его соседи из массива `w[]` есть `128 < 97 < 64`.
Сперва проверим разницу между первым: `128 - 97 = 31`, а потом и вторым: `97 - 64 = 33`.
Видем, что `31 < 33`, по-этому `n = w[i] (тоесть 128) - n`. А в другом случаи `n -= w[i + 1] (тоесть 64, а не 128)`.
Делаем так до тех пор, пока `n > 0`.

**Но, могу ли я считать это алгоритмом перебора?** Я же здесь толком то и ничего не перебираю. **Возможно Вы знаете какой-то другой вариант решения нужным мне способом!?**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int w[] = { 1024, 512, 256, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1 };

int neighbor(int n) {
    int i = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
        if (n - w[i] < 0) {
            i++;
        }
        if (n - w[i] >= 0) {
            return i;
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    int i, count = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
        i = neighbor(n) - 1;
        if (w[i] - n < n - w[i + 1]) {
            count++;
            n = w[i] - n;
        } else if (w[i] - n >= n - w[i + 1]) {
            n -= w[i + 1];
            count++;
        }
    }

    cout << count << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Понятно, что граммовый набор является стандартным и состоит из гирек весом в 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512 и 1024 грамм* А зачем нужна последняя гиря?

Comment: @Akina, это я уже не знаю..

Comment: *будем считать, что волшебным образом на прошедшей олимпиаде оказалось, что вес каждого спортсмена в точности мог быть измерен только килограммовым набором. Найти количество гирь.* Этих данных недостаточно для ответа на вопрос. Если максимальный вес спортсмена менее 128 кг и если 128 или  более - дают разные ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Учитывая, что вес гирь это степени двойки, его можно рассматривать как набор бит в числе. Тогда нам будет проще работать в ними, как с обычными двоичными числами. Наша задача найти такой набор бит, который надо добавить к весу спортсмена и набор бит, которые положить на другую чашу. При этом нам надо что бы не было одинаковых бит среди добавленных на левую чашу и положенных на правую. Из всех вариантов нам надо выбрать тот, в котором будет минимальное количество бит в сумме из добавленных на левую и положенных на правую.

Просто пробуем перебрать все возможные наборы гирь, добавляемых на левую чашу. Если взять крайние случаи и вес спортсмена выходящий за рамки задачи нам надо будет проверить максимум 2047 вариантов.

```
int main() {
  int c,s,bits;
  int n=508;  // Вес спортсмена, находящегося на левой чаше весов
  int min=0xFFFF, min_c=0;
  for(c=0;c<=2047;c++) {
    s=n+c; // Добавляем набор гирь на левую чашу, получаем уравновешивающий
           // вес, необходимый на правой чаши
    if((s & c) != 0) // Если в добавленном наборе гирь на леву чашу
       continue;     // и необходимом наборе на правой чаше есть одинаковые
                     // гири - то не рассматриваем этот вариант

    s=s | c;         // Получаем сумму гирь на левой и правой чаше
    bits=0;
    for (; s; bits++) s &= (s - 1);  // И считаем их количество
    if(min > bits) {  // Если нашли количество меньшее, чем ранее, запоминаем
      min=bits;
      min_c=c;
    }
  }
  printf("min=%d for left %d right %d\n",min,min_c,min_c+n);
}
```

Comment: Хорошо, а если набор гирь будет состоять из непарных чисел?

Comment: @entithat Я делаю решение строго для указанной задачи. Я стараюсь найти оптимальный вариант исходя из ее точной постановки. Если задача изменяется, то и решение может быть иным. Хотя в данном случае решение будет почти такое же, только биты нельзя будет рассматривать в обычном двоичном понимании, а придется представлять, что каждый из них представляет некое другое число. т.е. обычной арифметикой тут уже не выйдет. Придется вычислять вес побитно

Comment: Но можем ли мы считать такие подобные решения алгоритмами перебора?

Comment: @entithat Ну цикл перебирающий все возможные наборы гирь присутствует. А то что следующий, возможный набор формируется просто операцией ++, а не выборкой значений из массива, так это другой вопрос. Даже с массивом я вполне возможно пошел бы так же, просто каждый бит числа обозначал бы ячейку массива, которую надо взять в расчет.

Comment: Отлично. То, что надо. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Мое решение имеет идею перебора , давайте представим , что каждому предмету мы можем сопоставить число **1**  , если мы его берем на левые весы(то есть они прибавляют вес спортсмену) , число **0** , если они не используются и **-1** если они противовес спортсмену.Тогда мы сможем перебрать все значение за **3^(k)** , где k - количество предметов для задачи это **531441** операций , что нас устраивает.Код задачи приведен ниже.[Засчитаное решение на e-olymp](https://www.e-olymp.com/uk/submissions/3906267)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int x , p = 8;
int arr[12] = {0 , 1 , 2 , 4 , 8 , 16 , 32 , 64 , 128 , 256 , 512 , 1024} , k = 0;//индексация массива с елиницы
void du(int c , int r[12])
{
    if(c == 11)//когда мы набрали нужное количество гирь
    {  
        k++;

        int sum = 0 , l = 0;
        for(int i = 1;i < 12;i++)//проходим по предметам
        {
            sum += arr[i] * r[i];//в зависимости от места прибавляем , отнимаем или ничего не делаем
            if(r[i])
                l++;    
        }

        if(sum == x)
        {
            p = min(l , p);//нам нужно минимальное количество
        }
        return ;
    }
    //вызов всех возможных вариантов
    r[c+1] = 0;
    du(c+1 , r);
    r[c+1] = 1;
    du(c+1 , r);
    r[c+1] = -1;
    du(c+1  , r);
}

int main()
{

    cin >> x;
    int arr[12] = {0};//текущий набор(0 , 1 ,-1)согласно описанию више
    du(0 , arr);
    cout << p;//вывод ответа
}
```